# How to maintain mark-up indent level for each iteration of a for loop?

Tags: pug

My data from a database query sorted by `FamilyId` is as follows:

```
|FamilyId| Name   |
|    1   |   x    |
|    1   |   y    |
|    2   |   a    |
|    2   |   b    |
|    2   |   c    |
```

I want to achieve:

```
<div>
  <img src='1.jpg' />
</div>
<div>
  <p>x</p>
  <p>y</p>
</div>

<div>
  <img src='2.jpg' />
</div>
<div>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
</div>
```

I used the following, where the data is in `data`:

```
- var fid = null
for row in data
  -var newFamily = fid!==row.FamilyId
  if newFamily
     - fid = row.FamilyId
     div
       img(src='#{row.FamilyId}.jpg')
     div
       p #{row.Name} 
  else
       p #{row.Name}
```

The output is ok except for the row generated by the last line in the Jade script. It is not a child of the second `div` even though the indent level is correct. It looks like each iteration of the `for` loop resets the indent level to the beginning of the `for` block. The output is like:

```
<div>
  <img src='1.jpg' />
</div>
<div>
  <p>x</p>
</div>
<p>y</p>
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the indents in an else block continue from the then block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573633/does-the-indents-in-an-else-block-continue-from-the-then-block)

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through the data twice:

```
for row in data
   -var newFamily = fid!==row.FamilyId
   if newFamily
      - fid = row.FamilyId
      div
         img(src='#{row.FamilyId}.jpg')
      for row2 in data
          if fid == row2.FamilyId
             div
                p #{row2.Name}
```

Comment: That will create a *new* `div`, which is not what I want.  I want the `p` element to be always inside the `div` that was created at the start of a new family.

Comment: @OldGeezer see my edit. You'll want to loop through the data twice, the second time being every time a new FamilyId is found.

Comment: I solved it by first jsonifying the data before passing to Jade.  That added a chunk of code.  I am still interested in whether there's a solution if I used the original non-normalized data format.

Comment: @OldGeezer you can't loop through the data twice like in my edit?

Comment: I didn't, because it would be an O(n^2) penalty. My data is not sorted by FamilyId, it is just grouped by FamilyId.